# Oracle SQL Query Simplification of query a involving multiple schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query similar to below (simplified the query - my query is much more complex) where all the columns in "select" are the same. The only difference is that I have run the query on 6 different schema. I am currently using union to retrieve the data - however the query looks large and unreadable. is there a more elegant approach that I could use?

```
select name , employeeid , date from STRDB1.employee where...........
UNION
select name , employeeid , date from STRDB2.employee where...........
UNION
select name , employeeid , date from STRDB3.employee where...........
UNION
select name , employeeid , date from STRDB4.employee where...........
```

Comment: You could wrap it with `VIEW` and use `SELECT * FROM my_view`...

Comment: I don't have permission to create a view in this prod db...

Comment: Sadly, there's no generic `FROM *.employee`.  It's on my wish list alongside `SELECT * (EXCEPT foo, bar)`.  That said, @lad2025's CTE example is probably about as close to "elegant" as you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `common table expression`/subquery to combine it once and do the rest of operations in main query:

```
WITH cte_name AS
(
  select name , employeeid , date from STRDB1.employee where...........
  UNION
  select name , employeeid , date from STRDB2.employee where...........
  UNION
  select name , employeeid , date from STRDB3.employee where...........
  UNION
  select name , employeeid , date from STRDB4.employee where...........
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_name
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Thanks Lad , but I assume there is no way around repeating the same query for different schema.